# PHP Login check

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm getting a problem with my checkLogin function.

The problem is, it always says 'You are not logged in'

this is how I $_POST from my forum

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['login'])){
    extract($_POST);
    $gebruiker = new Gebruiker();

    if ($gebruiker->checkLogin($password, $login)) {
      echo "Welcome";
    }else {
      echo "You are not logged in";
    }
  }

 ?>
```

This is the function I'm using to checkLogin

```
function checkLogin($org_password, $login){
       $db = new Db();
       $conn = $db->getConnectie();
       $query = "SELECT * FROM gebruiker WHERE login = :login";
       $sth = $conn->prepare($query);
       $sth->bindParam(':login', $login, PDO::PARAM_STR);
       $sth->execute();
       $sth->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'Gebruiker');
       $gebruiker = $sth->fetch();

       if ($gebruiker && password_verify($org_password, $gebruiker->getPassword())) {
         return $gebruiker;
       }else {
         return false;
       }
     }
```

Comment: Can you show the HTML form, and how you construct the `Gebruiker` and `Db` class? You should also enable PHP error-reporting, it might give you a clue.

Comment: I'm not getting any php errors, and its enabled. Yeah sure I will show the HTML form and the construct of Gebruiker & Db classes. I will submit it on git and give you the link, one minute please

Comment: https://github.com/buryo/oo-php

Here I submited, thanks for your help Qirel

Comment: Seems to me like there is an issue with how you pass arguments to your `setFetchMode()`, I suggest you read the manual on that. Using `PDO::FETCH_CLASS`, it needs 3parameters?

Comment: Thanks I will do a research on it. But I'm using the same arguments (setFetchModel()) somewhere too, and it works fine.

Comment: Actually, what is the length of your password column in your database? That might be silently failing you if it's shorter than 60

Comment: I'd start by checking things step by step: does the query inside the function execute? Does it return the values you expect? Does ` password_verify()` return true with those variables? Checking these things will likely point you in the right direction.

Comment: the length of my password column in my database can up to 45 characters, but I'm using Hashcode, can it be over 45 characters?

Comment: Thank you I will work on it right now!!

Comment: What do you mean "Hashcode" though? I looked quickly through your code, I couldn't find where you hash it.  In any case, 45 sound like it's too short, and the password turnicates. Should be at least 60, but there isn't a reason why it can't be 255. See http://php.net/password_hash

Comment: $gebruiker->setPassword(password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT));
This is what I'm using for my registerm and also I can see in my workbench that its working fine. I have only hashpasswords which are max. 45charachters

Comment: Well there you go ;-) update the column to be at least 60 characters (255 is fine, might as well set it to that) and insert/update the passwords again, and try again. 45 is too short, and mysql will turnicate the password, thus silently failing the `password_verify()`

Comment: Alright thanks I will do it right now